# Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. How to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having this error in react-redux. I don't know how to solve it. I wanted to send a param which is taken from an api to another api and fetch results.

This is my store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import rootReducer from "./Reducers/rootReducer";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {},
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk), composeWithDevTools())
);

export default store;
```

This is my reducer code:

```
import * as types from "../Actions/types";

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  table: [],
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.payload,
      };
    case types.FETCH_TABLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        table: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
  }
};

export default postReducer;
```

This is my action code

```
export const getData = (from_userpart) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.getData(from_userpart);
    dispatch({
      type: types.FETCH_TABLE,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

When i use this code on the parent component,it works but i want to use that in my child component but it gives this error as i mentioned on the label. How to solve that?

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData(phone));
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting of your store, your enhancer should come second.

```
let composeEnhancers = null
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
} else {
  composeEnhancers = compose
}
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Comment: I edited the answer, don't forget to install redux devtools.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=fr

Comment: I am so new in redux. But what should i write in .env file. I don't use it in my folder except my backend. Beside it still don't work :/

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that i had imported my function from api folder not the action one. It works now